# Calling different methods with the same signature using a template like mechanism

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, methods

I have this code:

```
struct C
{
   int d1;
   int d2;
};

struct A
{
      void  write(C data)
      {
      }
};

struct B
{
      void use(C data)
      {
      }
};
```

Now I want to define a new class that uses `A` or `B` and call their `write` and `use` method. Something such as this:

```
template <class T>
struct D
{
     T t;
     D(T myT) { t=myT; }
     void myFunct(C data)
     {
         // t.????(data);
     }
};
```

As you can see if the two classes had similar method names, then it would be easy to implement `D`, but since `A` and `B` have different methods, then I need to tell compiler which method it should use. How can I do this?

I don't want to change `A` or `B` and also I don't want to create a subclass of `A` and `B` to create a method with the same name.

I want a way to tell the compiler which method to use as part of the template, is it possible?

Comment: You can use dynamic casting and check whether T is A or B, then call function of cast variable

Comment: @mahdi_12167 - Don't post answers in the comment section

Comment: @mahdi_12167 That requires `A` and `B` to be polymorphic, and negates the no-runtime-overhead benefit introduced by `D` being a template.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can pass a [pointer to member-function](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members) as a second template parameter to `D`:

```
template <class T, void (T::*fun)(C)>
struct D
{
    T t;

    void myFunct(C data)
    {
        (t.*fun)(data);
    }
};
```

You can then create `D` objects doing:

```
D<A, &A::write> da;
D<B, &B::use> db;
```

Answer (score 9):

You can easily do this using your own trait class:

```
template <class T>
struct DTraits;

template <>
struct DTraits<A> {
  static void call(A &obj, C data) { obj.write(data); }
};

template <>
struct DTraits<B> {
  static void call(B &obj, C data) { obj.use(data); }
};

template <class T>
struct D
{
  void myFunct(C data)
  {
    DTraits<T>::call(t, data);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness here is another possible solution which uses `if constexpr`, type traits and requires *C++17* support:

```
void myFunct(C data)
{
   if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, A>) {
       t.write(data);
   } else {
       t.use(data);
   }
}
```

[**Example**](https://godbolt.org/g/rcL45Y)